# How to use canvas for parsing imageData from video without appending canvas to the page?

Tags: javascript, canvas, qr-code

I have `Webcam` class, that uses for capturing data from webcam. This class streames data to video tag and also draw it on canvas., Also I have `QRScanner` class, that uses for parsing QR code from `imageData` of canvas.

```
class Webcam {
    constructor(videoTag, canvasTag) {
        // using for real-time video capture
        this.videoTag = videoTag;
        // qr scanner parses imageData from this element
        this.canvasTag = canvasTag;
        // waiting for qr code here
        this.captureArea = {
            x: 100,
            y: 60,
            width: 120,
            height: 120
        }

        // getting access to webcam
        navigator.mediaDevices
            .getUserMedia({
                video: true
            })
            .then(stream => this.videoTag.srcObject = stream)
            .catch(console.log);
    }

    capture() {
        setInterval(() => {
            let ctx = this.canvasTag.getContext('2d');
            ctx.drawImage(this.videoTag, 0, 0, 320, 240);
            // drawing capture area
            ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
            // this arguments also should be passed into qr scanner
            ctx.strokeRect(
                this.captureArea.x,
                this.captureArea.y,
                this.captureArea.width,
                this.captureArea.height
            );
        }, 100);
    }
}

class QRScanner {
    constructor(canvas, router, captureArea) {
        this.canvas = canvas;
        this.router = router;
        this.captureArea = captureArea;
        this.qrCode = null;
    }

    scan() {
        setInterval(() => {
            let imageData = this.canvas
                .getContext('2d')
                .getImageData(
                    this.captureArea.x,
                    this.captureArea.y,
                    this.captureArea.width,
                    this.captureArea.height
                ).data;

            // parsing qr code from canvas
            this.qrCode = jsQR(imageData, this.captureArea.width, this.captureArea.height);

            if (this.qrCode) {
                router.redirect(Router.pages.result, this.qrCode);
                let resultPage = document.querySelector('#result .qr-code-data');
                resultPage.innerHTML = this.qrCode.data;
            }
        }, 100);
    }
}

<div id="scan">
    <video id="video" width="320" height="240" autoplay title="Real-time video stream from webcam"></video>
    <canvas id="preview" width="320" height="240" title="Capture area for QR code"></canvas>
</div>
```

This works as expected, but when I removes `canvas` element from page and trying to use temporary canvas (using `document.createElement('canvas')` without appending to the page) - this solution do not work. Does it possible to using temporary `canvas` for getting `video` `imageData` without appending this canvas to the page?

P.S. I'm using https://github.com/cozmo/jsQR

Comment: Why are you doing `ctx.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0, 320, 240);` right after drawing the `videoTag`? Also canvas elements have a default width height when they aren't set, you never set those for you created canvas so it is going to default to 300 x 150 (at least that is what my chrome's default is). So your image is going to be cut off. Try setting those to what you need and try again

Comment: @PatrickEvans this is typo! Thank you, I removed this from code.

Comment: @PatrickEvans I setted width and height to my temporary canvas and all works fine! Thanks a lot! If you add your comment as answer - I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Canvas elements have a default width height when they aren't explicitly set. Since you never set those for you created canvas it is going to default to 300 x 150, at least for Chrome might be different for other browsers implementations.

```js
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
console.log(canvas.width,canvas.height)
```

And since this default size is different than the size that you are trying to draw the image/video to there is going to be some cropping going on and therefore effecting your QR library from properly reading the image.

Just set the width and height to what you need

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
canvas.width = 320;
canvas.height = 240;
```

Comment: 300×150 is per specs. All browsers will use these values as default. And don't use hard-coded values, moreover when dealing with a webcam stream, each user will have a different device outputting a video of different quality. Use videoElement's videoWidth and videoHeight instead.